# Getting a project that uses Qt working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, include

I downloaded a Github project that uses Qt 4.8 for GUI stuff, and am now trying to open the project in VS 2013. However, I'm not sure what to do about all the `#include <Qt...>` statements scattered throughout the project.

My first thought was to install Qt via the Qt website and cross my fingers, but that didn't work. How can I get VS 2013 to properly include the Qt files that this project requires? I guess I need to explictly tell the linker to include them, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Another option might be to do something with the .dll files included with the source code I downloaded from GitHub. Here's a screenshot of what I've got:

[image]

However, I'm not sure what the relationship between a .dll file and a `#include` header is.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is a picture of what I mean about VS not including the Qt stuff properly: [image]

And here is a partial error list (the other errors follow a similar pattern):

[image]

Edit: Here is a link to the Github page of the project I'm trying to get running: https://github.com/Y-Vladimir/SmartDeblur

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using Qt Creator? It is designed with Qt in mind...

Comment: I've never used it, this way is the only way I know of to get a Github project working is VS

Comment: Regarding the errors in the project, we can't actually see what they are, all we can see is that there _is_ an error. Can you tell us more? Perhaps an error message?

Comment: could we have a look at the github page (assuming it is open source)?

Comment: I've included the info

Comment: It looks like you aren't pointing the compiler to the directory with the Qt header files

Comment: Looking through the Qt folder I can see a bunch of .dll files, but no headers. Do you have any idea where can I find " the directory with the Qt header files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not so much with Qt as it is with a lack of understanding of how C++ programs are compiled and linked together. There are lots of resources online that can help you understand this critical information that will make your life a whole lot easier.

To get you round your current problem, I suggest:

1. Go to Qt [community version](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) download page.
2. Download and install the version specifically for Visual Studio 2013.
3. Go back to the download page, download and install the Visual Studio plugin from the "Other Downloads" section near the bottom of the page.
4. When the VS Plugin has finished installing, you'll see a new menu called "Qt". Inside that you can import the .pro file from your project.

Comment: I had some trouble getting things running in VS, the workaround that ended up working for me was using Qt Creator to do basically the same thing you suggested. Once Creator was installed it was just a matter of double clicking the .pro file and letting the import wizard do the rest.

Comment: VS seemed to need a length configuration step involving running config.exe from the VS command line. I did that a couple hours ago and it's still running.

Comment: And as for not understanding how C++ programs are compiled and linked together, I understand the general principles involved (I think) but not so much the nitty-gritty details . My understanding of the reason for the problem was that the compiler didn't know where to look for the Qt libraries, and I didn't know where to point it (I still don't). Is that correct?

Comment: If you needed to run config.exe then you installed the wrong binaries and were forced to compile the libraries for VS. That's why I said you need to to install the libraries specifically for VS.

Comment: Every time you create a C++ project (no matter what compiler you use), you need to specify the location of all 3rd party library files. In VS, you do this via the project properties. If you have Qt and the Qt plugin for VS installed, the plugin does this for you automatically.